# Stop MDI child form flickering when moves on MDI parent borderless form edges

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a project which contains **MDI child forms**. I have make my MDI child forms stop moving when user is trying to **drag them out** of **MDI parent** borderless form's edges. But, if user insists, MDI child form **flickering** like crazy!!!

**Note** that I have already set my forms to `DoubleBuffered = True` and I have also add `me.Refresh()` and `me.parentform.Refresh()` at the end of event.

Any idea what else can I do?

---

Here is an **edited** example of my code...

First we have the **custom title bar control** and this is the needed part of it's code:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class cmosTitleBar

Region "Custom events."
    Public Event FormTitleBar_DoubleClick_Plus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Public Event FormTitleBar_MouseDown_Plus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Public Event FormTitleBar_MouseMove_Plus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Public Event FormTitleBar_MouseEnter_Plus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Public Event FormTitleBar_MouseLeave_Plus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
End Region

Region "Form Code."

    Dim NewPoint As New System.Drawing.Point
    Dim X, Y As Integer

Region "FormTitleBar Events."
    Private Sub FormTitleBar_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FormTitleBar.DoubleClick
        RaiseEvent FormTitleBar_DoubleClick_Plus(sender, e)
        Call PreventFlickering()
    End Sub
    Private Sub FormTitleBar_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles FormTitleBar.MouseDown, FormIcon.MouseDown, MyBase.MouseDown
        If Not ParentForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized Then
            X = Control.MousePosition.X - ParentForm.Location.X
            Y = Control.MousePosition.Y - ParentForm.Location.Y
        End If
        RaiseEvent FormTitleBar_MouseDown_Plus(sender, e)
    End Sub
    Private Sub FormTitleBar_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles FormTitleBar.MouseMove, FormIcon.MouseMove, MyBase.MouseMove
        If Not ParentForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized Then
            If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
                NewPoint = Control.MousePosition
                NewPoint.X -= (X)
                NewPoint.Y -= (Y)
                ParentForm.Location = NewPoint
            End If
        End If
        Call PreventChildMoveOut()
        RaiseEvent FormTitleBar_MouseMove_Plus(sender, e)
        RaiseEvent FormIcon_MouseMove_Plus(sender, e)
        Call PreventFlickering()
    End Sub
    Private Sub FormTitleBar_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FormTitleBar.MouseEnter, FormIcon.MouseEnter
        If ParentForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal Then
            FormTitleBar.Cursor = Cursors.NoMove2D
            FormIcon.Cursor = Cursors.NoMove2D
        Else
            FormTitleBar.Cursor = Cursors.Default
            FormIcon.Cursor = Cursors.Default
        End If
        RaiseEvent FormTitleBar_MouseEnter_Plus(sender, e)
    End Sub
    Private Sub FormTitleBar_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FormTitleBar.MouseLeave
        RaiseEvent FormTitleBar_MouseLeave_Plus(sender, e)
    End Sub
End Region

End Region

Region "Custom subs."
    Private Sub PreventFlickering()
        If Me.ParentForm.IsMdiChild = True Then
            Me.ParentForm.Refresh()
            Me.ParentForm.ParentForm.Refresh()
        Else
            Me.ParentForm.Refresh()
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub PreventChildMoveOut()
        If ParentForm.IsMdiChild = True Then
            If ParentForm.Left < ParentForm.MdiParent.ClientRectangle.Left Then
                ParentForm.Left = ParentForm.MdiParent.ClientRectangle.Left
                If ParentForm.Top < ParentForm.MdiParent.ClientRectangle.Top Then
                    ParentForm.Top = ParentForm.MdiParent.ClientRectangle.Top
                ElseIf ParentForm.Bottom > ParentForm.MdiParent.ClientRectangle.Height - 98 Then
                    ParentForm.Top = ParentForm.MdiParent.ClientRectangle.Bottom - ParentForm.Height - 98
                End If
            ElseIf ParentForm.Right > ParentForm.MdiParent.ClientRectangle.Width Then
                ParentForm.Left = ParentForm.MdiParent.ClientRectangle.Right - ParentForm.Width
                If ParentForm.Top < ParentForm.MdiParent.ClientRectangle.Top Then
                    ParentForm.Top = ParentForm.MdiParent.ClientRectangle.Top
                ElseIf ParentForm.Bottom > ParentForm.MdiParent.ClientRectangle.Height - 98 Then
                    ParentForm.Top = ParentForm.MdiParent.ClientRectangle.Bottom - ParentForm.Height - 98
                End If
            ElseIf ParentForm.Top < ParentForm.MdiParent.ClientRectangle.Top Then
                ParentForm.Top = ParentForm.MdiParent.ClientRectangle.Top
            ElseIf ParentForm.Bottom > ParentForm.MdiParent.ClientRectangle.Height - 98 Then
                ParentForm.Top = ParentForm.MdiParent.ClientRectangle.Bottom - ParentForm.Height - 98
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
End Region

End Class
```

Here is the needed code of my **borderless MDI parent** form which contains my **custom title bar control**:

```
Public Class MainForm

Region "Form Code."
        Private Sub SettingsToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SettingsToolStripMenuItem.Click
            SettingsForm.MdiParent = Me
            SettingsForm.Show()
        End Sub
    End Region

End Class
```

Into my **borderless MDI child** forms which also contains my **custom title bar control** there is no code for this action cause everything (until now) happens into **custom title bar control**'s code.

Comment: MDI doesn't work right unless the border is the normal sizable border.  You are fighting an uphill battle.  MDI is basically an obsolete paradigm.

Answer (score 1):

It is flickering because you are trying to restrict location to >= 0, and location moves to -1 then 0. Then as you try to coerce the form past your boundary, the location is really -1, 0, -1, 0, etc. You don't want to allow it to get to -1 in the first place. So instead restrict the cursor area when moving the mdi child.

To test, make a project with two forms.

- MdiParentForm with `IsMdiContainer = true`
- MdiChildForm

MdiParentForm code:

```
Public Class MdiParentForm

    Private child As Form

    Private Sub MdiParentForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        child = New MdiChildForm()
        child.MdiParent = Me
        child.Show()
    End Sub

End Class
```

MdiChildForm code:

```
Public Class MdiChildForm

    Private mouseIsDown As Boolean = False
    Private myParent As Form
    Private myRectangle As System.Drawing.Rectangle
    Private myCursorLocation As System.Drawing.Point
    Private myBorderWidth As Integer
    Private myTitlebarHeight As Integer

    Private Sub MdiChildForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        myParent = Me.MdiParent
    End Sub

    Private Sub MdiChildForm_MouseCaptureChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.MouseCaptureChanged
        If mouseIsDown Then
            myRectangle = myParent.Bounds
            myCursorLocation = Me.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)
            myBorderWidth = (Me.Width - Me.ClientSize.Width) / 2
            myTitlebarHeight = Me.Height - Me.ClientSize.Height - 2 * myBorderWidth
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub MdiChildForm_Move(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Move
        If mouseIsDown Then
            Cursor.Clip = New Rectangle(myRectangle.Left + myCursorLocation.X + myBorderWidth,
                                        myRectangle.Top + myCursorLocation.Y + myTitlebarHeight,
                                        myRectangle.Width - Me.Width - myBorderWidth,
                                        myRectangle.Height - Me.Height)
        Else
            Cursor.Clip = Nothing
        End If
    End Sub

    ' there is no event for title bar click, so use WndProc
    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
        Select Case m.Msg
            Case &H21
                mouseIsDown = True
            Case &H22
                mouseIsDown = False
        End Select
    End Sub

End Class
```

Since you are using custom controls, you may need to tweak the Cursor.Clip rectangle dimensions and coordinates inside `MdiChildForm_Move`.

Comment: Your answer is correct, it works if I make a new project and put all together but it can't fit into my project... It just don't work!!! Maybe I should give more details about it. I'll edit my question asap!!!